# How can I be informed through my computer if a new SMS is received?

Tags: sms, sync, notifications

While I'm working with my computer, my mobile lies next to me and every time I receive a new SMS or WhatsApp message, I have to grab the phone, read the message and answer it.

So it would be really nice, if there is an App or another possibility to connect my mobile phone with my computer via Bluetooth, WLAN or USB so that I can read and send SMS messages from my computer desktop.

This would have several advantages:

- It is easier to copy page content. A lot of time I'd like to send a SMS to someone with content on my computer. So I don't have to type it anymore but just copy & paste it
- My working process isn't disturbed as much it is if I have to grab my phone
- It is easier and faster to write with a keyboard than the mobile phone pad

So my questions are:

- is there any app/program that can do that?
- if not, would it be at least technically possible or are there any restrictions that prevent such an app?

Comment: Equivalent question on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/86076/send-sms-from-pc-through-android-phone (but not really a duplicate ;-) )

Comment: KDE Connect can do this and much more :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have Android, try Texdro. I tried a few of the other related apps and this worked the best for me. It allows you to send and receive texts from your computer. It also allows you to silence SMS notifications on your phone while the program is running so you can just be notified on your computer (or you can be notified on both). The free version of the app allows you only to connect via WiFi and the Pro version adds USB and Bluetooth options. I will probably be purchasing the pro version when I get some handy $$, mostly to support the dev, because WiFi connectivity works fine for me.

[Texdro - Desktop SMS for Android on AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/app/texdro-desktop-sms/com.crackedsun.texdro)

Android Market QR Code
[image: QR Code]

Comment: This appears to no longer be available in the Market, and I can't find it elsewhere.  The developer's site is down as well.

Answer (score 6):

There is this similar question in SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/86076/send-sms-from-pc-through-android-phone

[gtalksms](https://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/) allows you to send various commands (including sending sms) by sending a GTalk message to yourself which will trigger various events; note that you need a 3rd party Gtalk software (e.g. Pidgin) since the official Google Talk client does not allow you to send message to yourself, or alternatively you can use a different account for your phone. [Download link](http://market.android.com/details?id=com.googlecode.gtalksms) (open in Android) or scan QR:

[image: gtalk qr code]

also, if you're using Android 2.2 or higher and have the [ChromeToPhone apps](http://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chrometophone) (open in Android) installed, you can send arbitrary text in your clipboard (Copy-Paste buffer) to your phone using [FoxToPhone](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxtophone-aka-sendtophone/) (open in Firefox) or [ChromeToPhone](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/oadboiipflhobonjjffjbfekfjcgkhco) (open in Chrome) extension. Using FoxToPhone, right click on the Send to Phone button and click "Send clipboard", and whatever text in your clipboard will be send to the phone's clipboard, which you can paste to any textbox in Android by Long Press > Paste. [Download app](http://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chrometophone) (open in Android) or scan QR:

[image: chrome to phone apps market link]

Comment: Nice utils to bear in mind, but OP wanted to not have to pick up his phone as much as possible...

Comment: @Sparx: I haven't tried sending sms yet, but gtalksms can send and read sms without touching the phone.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like [Android Notifier](http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/downloads/list) delivers part of your request -- notifications and text of messages on your PC. I don't see the capability to reply, unfortunately. That seems a good feature though, perhaps you could request it of the developers.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with Google Voice, although it's perhaps not ideal since people would have to text your GVoice number and not your actual phone number.  There's the web interface of course as well as a great Chrome extension (if you use Chrome).

Comment: Google Voice is only available in the US right now.  This solution might not be applicable.

Comment: I'm in Canada; it's simple to get it outside the US.  Harder to use it for phone calls than for texts though.

Answer (score 4):

**Mighty Text** is another solution, It provides SMS from your computer, sync'd with your Android phone.

[Official website](http://mightytext.net/)

[Play Store App page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.texty.sms#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLnRleHR5LnNtcyJd)

[image: QR code]

Comment: I used to use another app but then I found Mighty Text. It has the best interface I've seen so far. Love using the Chrome extension.

Answer (score 3):

I know that pdanet allows this, but I have only used it while tethering my phone. However I feel like there should be someway to just use the SMS capability without using your phone as a modem.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative that has not been mentioned yet, and that I find rather handy, is one of the SMS backup utilities.

E.g. [SMS Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sms-backup/tv.studer.smssync) (which is open source [SMS Backup](http://code.google.com/p/android-sms/)), will backup your SMS to a label of your choice on GMail. In that way you get them in your standard email client and the GMail web interface as soon as you receive them on your phone.

The advantage of such solution is that it fits in your usual email workflow. Also you get the great GMail search capabilities and the fact that your text are available everywhere through the GMail web interface.

There are other apps that do the same thing (e.g. [SMS Backup+](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sms-backup/com.zegoggles.smssync) and [Backup to Gmail](http://www.appbrain.com/app/backup-to-gmail/net.cpedia.backup2gmail), personally I use [SMS Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sms-backup/tv.studer.smssync)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried out the Messaging capabilities, but [MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/en/highlight.php) connects via Wi-Fi to your PC (software needed on device + PC), is freeware and allows you to sync your contacts / messages etc. to your PC. One of the options available also  is to pop up a notification when an incoming SMS appears on your PC.

There's also support for a Chat based conversation via SMS.

Check it out - see if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

[EasySMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.fireblade.easysms) lets you read/write SMS in your web browser. You can connect via wifi, USB, or Bluetooth.

Answer (score 2):

Another "remotely control the phone" type option would be [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid), which will handle SMS and pretty much everything else.  It's also free.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the full version of RemoteSMS and there's been no looking back for me. I don't mind sending texts or even the occasional email on my Nexus One, but I'm sitting in front of my computer all day, anyway, and typing on a keyboard is such a dramatic improvement.

I've never tried the limited free version, but such an edition exists.

I could list the features, but I'll just direct you to where all of that information (plus screenshots) already exists:

[RemoteSMS Full Version](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.grrzzz.remotesmsfull)

[RemoteSMS Free Version](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.grrzzz.sms)

Answer (score 1):

[MAXS](http://projectmaxs.org) (Modular Android XMPP Suite) notifies you over [XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) if a new SMS is received. It also allows you to control various aspects of Android, includes a SMS/Call/Battery notification and reply system. Additionally it is able to send and receive files to and from your Android device. There are many other features too.

Using XMPP as transport, the "desktop app" can be every XMPP Client. Which is one of the big advantages of MAXS, as it does not need a dedicated desktop app. Although there may be one in the future.

<sup>Note: According to the FAQ I have to disclose that I am involved into MAXS. MAXS is an open source GPLv3 licensed Android app. Everyone can contribute.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

See **Remote Notifier** in the [F-Droid](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=notifier&fdid=org.damazio.notifier&fdpage=1) free & open source repository or on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.damazio.notifier). It's open source and contains no ads/malware.