# Messages on computer?

Tags: usb-connection-mode, sms, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I be informed through my computer if a new SMS is received?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4738/how-can-i-be-informed-through-my-computer-if-a-new-sms-is-received)

I have the [LG Optimus One p500](http://www.lg.com/uk/mobile-phones/mobile-phones/LG-android-mobile-phone-P500.jsp). It comes with LG PC Suite IV which is great.
It allows me to download my sms messages to/from the computer fine.

However I must manually check if there are new messages.

Is there any program (for windows) which can listen for sms messages in android and download them to the computer automatically then alert you?

Answer (score 3):

There's [Android notifier](http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/) and [SMS2PC](https://market.android.com/details?id=uk.org.scottishgeek.sms2pcpaid.androidclient&feature=search_result).  [PDANet](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pdanet&feature=search_result) will also do it, along with tethering.

Comment: +1 for android notifier, although I would like a true "Growl for Android" that can forward to a PC/Mac running Growl and receive from other Growl clients.

Comment: actually, I want to give android notifier another +1 because it looks like they implemented Growl Notification Protocol...

Answer (score 3):

There's also [gtalksms](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.googlecode.gtalksms) which will send any SMS messages back out through Google Talk.  I registered an extra Gmail account for the phone to use and it just sends them to me in the normal chat client I use on my PC.