# How can I forward SMS via Jabber (XMPP) to read them on a PC?

Tags: sms, xmpp

I want my received SMS to automagically be forwarded via Jabber (XMPP), so I can read them on my current PC.

I don't want to send SMS from my computer, though I would not mind the feature as an extra bonus.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why Jabber? Try Air Droid..

Comment: @SachinShekhar Because I want it :) I want to instaread my SMS on my current PC.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4738/how-can-i-be-informed-through-my-computer-if-a-new-sms-is-received and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/how-do-i-send-sms-from-pc-through-android-phone-or-to-android-phone

Comment: If you want this for a separate phone number (not relayed over your android device or similar) you could look into https://jmp.chat

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[GTalkSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.gtalksms) ([Google Project Page](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/)) does what you want (and much more).

Edit: After actively developing GTalkSMS, I decided that it's time to spawn a new project called [MAXS](http://projectmaxs.org). [See my second answer.](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/60879/440)

<sup>Note: According to the FAQ I have to disclose that I am involved into GtalkSMS. GTalkSMS is an open source GPL licensed Android app. Everyone can contribute.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

[MAXS](http://projectmaxs.org) (Modular Android XMPP Suite) does what you want, and much more. You can reply to incoming SMS messages or send them via XMPP. All you need is a standard XMPP client on your PC.

<sup>Note: According to the FAQ I have to disclose that I am involved into MAXS. MAXS is an open source GPLv3 licensed Android app. Everyone can contribute.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If XMPP is not a must have you should check out [MightyText](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=mightytext) app and [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mightytext-sendreceive-sm/dkfhfaphfkopdgpbfkebjfcblcafcmpi).

I use it every day. You don't need to have your phone near you because you see SMS messages and you can respond from the app. You can even initiate a phone call from the extension (web app).

Comment: @al-everett, thanks for correction, I learn a lot with that :)

Comment: Always happy to help.