# Can I forward/reply calls/SMS to PC?

Tags: sms, calls, remote-control

I wonder if it's possible to forward calls or SMS to PC where I can then reply or at least get notified of a call/SMS? For example, calls might be forwarded to Skype, is it possible?

Comment: Related: [How can I be informed through my computer if a new SMS is received?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4738/how-can-i-be-informed-through-my-computer-if-a-new-sms-is-received), [How do I send SMS from PC through Android Phone or to Android Phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/how-do-i-send-sms-from-pc-through-android-phone-or-to-android-phone)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I be informed through my computer if a new SMS is received?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4738/how-can-i-be-informed-through-my-computer-if-a-new-sms-is-received)

Answer (score 4):

**As of June 2014, I've moved on and developed [MAXS](http://projectmaxs.org).** See my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/60885/).

*Below is the original answer.*

---

**[GTalkSMS](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/)** is an alternative for Android-notifier which works over **XMPP** (GTalk, Jabber). It allows you to control various aspects of Android, including an SMS/Call/Battery notification and reply system. Additionally, it is able to send and receive files to and from your Android device. There are many other features too.

Using XMPP as transport, the "desktop app" can be every XMPP Client. This is one of GTalkSMS's big advantages, as it does not need a dedicated desktop app.

<sup>Disclosure: I am involved in GTalkSMS. GTalkSMS is an open-source GPL-licensed Android app. Everyone can contribute.</sup>

Comment: Neato!  While I'm not sure it's all that handy for the OP, that is a nifty app...

Answer (score 2):

The free Windows program [MyPhoneExplorer](https://www.fjsoft.at/en/) and its companion Android app [MyPhoneExplorer Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client) (also free) enables you to:

- get notified of incoming texts (using a Windows tray tip, optionally with sound)
- read incoming texts and reply to them
- write and send new texts
- read and reply to all previously received and send texts on the phone

using an Android phone connected either via the local network (LAN/Wi-Fi), Bluetooth, or USB cable.

You can also:

- be notified of incoming calls, including who is calling, and
- pick up and hang up a call from the computer,

*but* you have to **conduct the actual call through the phone**, using the phone's speaker and microphone or a headset connected to the phone.

The program has many other nice features, including:

- backing up and archiving of your text messages (using a local archive of all text messages in which you can search, filter, organize into simple folders, reply to specific texts, etc.)
- edit text fields from the computer in any phone app, including copying text from the computer clipboard into the phone's text field (the client app installs a remotely controlled soft keyboard on the phone to be able to do this)
- making the computer keyboard act as a phone keyboard when the phone is connected to the computer via a USB cable
- taking screenshots from the phone when it is connected to the computer via a USB cable
- editing of contacts and calendar
- working with files on the phone, synchronising photos and other files between the phone and the computer
- getting Android notifications from all apps as Windows tray notifications.

The program has been a trustful companion for me for 8 years. It is mature and stable. It used to only work with Sony Ericsson phones (before Android) but now it also supports Android phones of any brand.

For a time in the past, the program was distributed with OpenCandy, which "recommended" other software to install during the installation, but that has luckily been removed now.

**Disclosure**: I am the Danish translator of MyPhoneExplorer. But I do it absolutely for free, simply because I love the program and want the translation I use daily to be of high quality.

Comment: I can confirm that this works really well.

Answer (score 1):

I have Google Voice set up which allows this. If you were to call or text my Google Voice number and I was signed into GMail in a web browser (I exclusively use Chrome) I can answer the call using either my phone or the computer. I can also send and receive text messages from the computer. I'm also able to answer calls using my house phone, too. I know that this doesn't answer your question but it may solve the problem of being unable to get the question answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Voice to have calls ring your cell phone and any other phone you like; as [vyse mentioned](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/22527/44325), you can use it directly with Google Chat, but with a little extra effort, you can hook it into any SIP phone like Skype.  This also works for SMS messages, which will show up in your email and you can reply to them exactly as if they were on your phone.

Aside from GV, there really aren't any good alternatives for what you want to do without setting up your own vPBX like FreeSWITCH or Asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

Highly recommend [SMSSync](http://smssync.ushahidi.com). It's opensource, it doesn't try to do too many things, and it does this specific thing very well.

Answer (score 1):

For SMS, I highly recommend [MightyText](https://mightytext.net/).
For controlling your phone, you can use [Airdroid](https://airdroid.com/), which is great.

For receiving calls on your computer, I haven't found any solution besides Google Voice, and I live outside the USA, so it's a bummer for me :-(

Answer (score 1):

[MAXS](http://projectmaxs.org) (Modular Android XMPP Suite) forwards all kinds of notifications (calls, SMS, etc) to your PC over [XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP). It also allows you to control various aspects of Android, including an SMS/Call/Battery notification and reply system. Additionally, it is able to send and receive files to and from your Android device. There are many other features too.

Using XMPP as transport, the "desktop app" can be every XMPP Client. This is one of the big advantages of MAXS, as it does not need a dedicated desktop app. Although there may be one in the future.

<sup>Disclosure: I am involved in MAXS. MAXS is an open-source GPLv3-licensed Android app. Everyone can contribute.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This works with [mysms.com](http://www.mysms.com). The app syncs your text messages and calls and you get notified via a popup window - similar to Skype.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Samsung Device, [SideSync](https://www.samsung.com/africa_en/support/side-sync/) is a great way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Sidesync has a lot of great features:

- Display your phone or table from your PC and control it.
- Send and receive phone calls from your PC
- Access all of your apps (like sending/reading SMS messages)
- See notifications from your device directly on your PC (like incoming SMS)
- Access your Phone/Tablet via USB or wireless on the same network
- Drag and drop files to and from device

Comment: My coworkers connect headsets to their PC, and access their phone via SideSync for most of their work day.