# HowTo : Android ICS Tethering & sending SMS from desktop

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, windows

I'm a long time Nokia user (currently on an E6) who is now considering the move to Android. I'm almost sold on the HTC One V. I will be buying the phone from a reseller, so no carrier restrictions will be in place.

Before I make the switch I wanted to know if the following are possible via Android apps or those specific to HTC.

1. USB and Bluetooth Tethering. Am not interested in WiFi tethering since that is definitely going to be a battery killer.
2. Sending and receiving SMS/text message via a desktop app for Windows 7 (over USB and Bluetooth)

Nokia Suite currently handles these two functions quite well. And frankly, these features are a must have for me to switch to Android on my primary phone.

Additionally, I'm not too keen on having to flash the phone with a custom ROM to enable these features.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: My three years old HTC desire does both of them perfectly. But for number 2 you have to install some third party apps. No root or custom ROM is required.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions at once. AFAIK Bluetooth tehtering is supported since ICS. For more information ask a new question or browse the related tags: [usb-tethering](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-tethering) and [bluetooth-tethering](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-tethering)

Comment: Don't accuse wifi of battery destroying before you try it.. Bluetooth could easily be just as bad. I have wifi on all the time and it uses less power than when it is off as there is no 3G searching

Comment: Hey CJK, based on my previous observations with WiFi tethering with Joiku hotspot - I've found that it drains the battery much faster than with Bluetooth tethering.

Comment: Please only ask *one* question per post. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The nice thing about Android is that there are many geeky Apps available. Some of them are even open source and free. So there are many different Apps for your task. Here are the ones I am aware of:

## Android Remote Notifier

[Project Page](http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/) - [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.damazio.notifier)
Forwards and send text messages via bluetooth

## GTalkSMS

[Project Page](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/) Forward and send text messages via XMPP

## Other

Can be found in the related questions on Android Enthusiasts:

- [How do I send SMS from PC through Android Phone or to Android Phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/how-do-i-send-sms-from-pc-through-android-phone-or-to-android-phone)
- [How can I be informed through my computer if a new SMS is received?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4738/how-can-i-be-informed-through-my-computer-if-a-new-sms-is-received)

Answer (score 1):

1. USB and BT tethering are available, provided your carrier hasn't modified Android to disable them - some carriers charge a premium for tethering.  Contact your carrier to find out for certain.
2. [DeskSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.desktopsms) is a great remote SMS app.  You can view, send and receive SMS from any web browser on any computer; the app then receives the request on your phone and sends the SMS from the phone itself.

Comment: Ah, but it looks like DeskSMS sends SMS over the Internet to the phone. Not quite what I'm looking for. The thought of a random 3rd party app getting access to my messages doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: True, it does go through a third party server (though it is that of a highly respected developer). For me, the convenience outweighs the other considerations (especially since I don't use SMS for anything other than trivial things).